# TCL vs. DSL vs. TTY vs. Feather - How to choose one over another?

Tags: distribution-choice, small-distribution

In my search for Linux distros that can run on extremely modest resources, I found the following alternatives:

1. TCL - [Tiny Core Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Core_Linux)
2. DSL - [Damn Small Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Small_Linux)
3. TTY - [ttylinux](http://www.minimalinux.org/ttylinux/)
4. Feather - [Feather Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather_Linux)

The comparison between these various options is mind boggling. It's like comparing between apples and oranges. I don't have the time to install and become proficient in all of them. I must chose only one.

Is there a recommended process for selecting the most suitable tiny linux distro?

Comment: "Extremely modest" suggests [OpenWrt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) or other distributions targetting the [embedded sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Embedded_Linux_distributions).

Comment: As @sr_ seems to be hinting at, what level of "modest" are we talking about here? A laptop with 500MHz/256MB?  A router? A webserver on a toaster? (that last one was done with NetBSD IIRC) And do you want just a command line or X11 too?

Comment: You are both correct. At this point @sr_'s answer satisfies me as I do need X11 and I don't want it for a router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first step is determining what you want...i.e. a complete Desktop environment with X11 and a graphical web browser?

> [ttylinux] provides a complete command line environment and is ready for Internet access.

Forget this, then.

Comparing the other three via their Wikipedia entries, I'd first drop Feather Linux as it seems **dormant**.

Then see [this note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Small_Linux#Current_status_of_the_project) on DSL's page:<sup>(1)</sup>

> Due to infighting among the project's originators and main developers, DSL development seems to be at a standstill, and the future of the project is uncertain, much to the dismay of many of the users.

By exclusion and from these four, **I'd end up with Tiny Core** (or maybe Micro Core without the graphical desktop but then you need another reason to exclude ttylinux).  Also note that [their core concepts](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/concepts.html) are interesting and probably differ from one is used to with other distributions.

Of course, many general-purpose distributions can probably be trimmed down to be resource-friendly, so Debian (especially [**Emdebian**](http://www.emdebian.org/)) (or Arch) could be a winner, too.  (Not to mention non-Linux OSes, e.g. {Net,Free,Open}BSD)

**(1) Edit:** [DSL *"is once again being actively developed"*](http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=07373) (as an anonymous edit request pointed out)

Comment: I couldn't expect a better answer than this. Thank you!

Comment: What about just busybox?